# HTTP Error 500 during search request - CiviCRM 5.1.1

Tags: wordpress, error, custom-search, error-page, advanced-search

I have a new installed CiviCRM 5.1.1 property on my server.

My current system configuration is:

Wordpress 4.9.6

The problem:
I importet a few contacts but I realized that besides using the search function in the upper left corner and using custom reports I receive an error 500 and no results.

For example, when I use contacts > find contacts I receive an Error 500 for the following URL:
http://mydomain.de/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/search
in Wordpress Debug Mode:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_DAO::disableFullGroupByMode() in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.mydomain.de/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:4848 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.mydomain.de/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Selector.php(1181): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->searchQuery(NULL, NULL, NULL, false, false, true) #1 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.mydomain.de/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(108): CRM_Contact_Selector->alphabetQuery() #2 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.mydomain.de/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(136): CRM_Utils_PagerAToZ::getDynamicCharacters(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector), false) #3 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.mydomain.de/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(52): CRM_Utils_PagerAToZ::createLinks(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector), NULL, false) #4 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.mydomain.de in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.mydomain.de/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php on line 4848

Could anybody please help with this issue?
I was trying to fix it for some time now and searched the whole forum with no result or hint.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with CiviCRM 5.1.1 that was patched in 5.1.2.   The details of the issue are here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.1/release-notes/5.1.2.md#synopsis

Download the new version from https://civicrm.org/download and update your site.

Comment: thanks a lot - I wish I would have found it somewhere.
I will try that in a minute and let you know if it worked.
Best regards,